# Check for any key in multidimension array

Tags: php, arrays

I have multidimensional array like this

```
$data["a"][2013][4] = some value;
$data["b"][2013][4] = some value;
```

Now I want to check if

`$data[whatever][2013]` exists ?  which should return `true` in this case.

//I don't know `whatever` variable value

I think I can do it with multi foreach loop. But wondering if there could be a simpler/shorter way ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) ?!

Comment: Does isset work like $data[][2013] ?  .. Coz i don't know 'whatever' variable //Sorry if I wasn't clear before

Comment: If you don't know the index for the first dimension. How do you want to know what you are checking? Or do you just want to know if there is a index with `2013` in the second dimension?

Comment: Coz i don't care about the first dimension. Whatever it be. I just care if ANY of the first dimension have the second dimension as 2013

Comment: Yes I just want to know if there is any index with `2013` in second dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
if(!empty(array_column($data, 2013)))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

If there is a second dimension with 2013 then it returns something, otherwise you would get a empty array

Comment: You might want to add that it is php 5.5+ only.

Comment: @jeroen I have done that back in 2014, but I think now that we live in 2015 php 5.5 should be minimum

Comment: I whish that were true :(

Comment: Thank You very much . array_column is something new I learn. 
Oh yes thanks @jeroen for version too. Upgrading from 5.4 to 5.5 .